# Java Out Of Range Error

Tags: java, data-structures

Why does the following return an IndexOutOfBoundsException? (Index 5, size 0)

```
gridList = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
gridList.add(5, 2);
```

I was under the impression that the constructor call initializes my arraylist to the size.

I'm quite new with java, so apologies.

Comment: The number you give is the *capacity* not the size.  The capacity is how many elements you can add without it resizing the underlying data structure, i.e. how many you expect the List to have, not what it does have.

Answer (score 6):

Calling that constructor just specifies an initial capacity, but has no effect on the size of the ArrayList (size will always be zero until you add anything). This is explained in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) and also evidenced by printing out that ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<Integer> gridList = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
System.out.println(gridList);

Output: []
```

If you want to initialize an ArrayList with 9 Integers (for example, nine zeroes), try this '[convenience implementation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/convenience.html)':

```
ArrayList<Integer> gridList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(9, 0));
System.out.println(gridList);

Output: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

As you can see this fills the ArrayList with values during initialization, so you can now call `gridList.add(5, 2);` without an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 4):

The `ArrayList` is [initialized with a capacity](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) of 9 but the list is empty. Thus you cannot add an element at the position 5 since this position does not exist in the list.

Answer (score 3):

Please follow the source code of ArrayList, you can see that size and capacity are different concept.
`checkBoundInclusive()` method compares `index` with `size` not `capacity`.

```
public ArrayList(int capacity)
   {
     // Must explicitly check, to get correct exception.
     if (capacity < 0)
       throw new IllegalArgumentException();
     data = (E[]) new Object[capacity];
   }


   public void add(int index, E e)
   {
      checkBoundInclusive(index);
      modCount++;
      if (size == data.length)
        ensureCapacity(size + 1);
     if (index != size)
        System.arraycopy(data, index, data, index + 1, size - index);
      data[index] = e;
      size++;
    }


    private void checkBoundInclusive(int index)
    {
      // Implementation note: we do not check for negative ranges here, since
      // use of a negative index will cause an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,
      // a subclass of the required exception, with no effort on our part.
      if (index > size)
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Index: " + index + ", Size: "
                                            + size);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's still an empty list (size 1, only index available is 0). Just the capacity is 9. Once the capacity has reached capacity, the `ArrayList` will expand.

Note: size and capacity are two different thing.

Comment: Any tip for a fast/efficient way to initialize an arraylist to that capacity with 0 values?

Comment: If you mean initialize with a size greater than 0, you can't, unless you initialize it will another list, but then it wouldn't be empty.  You have to add values before the size will increase. If you want to use indices, try using an array instead of arraylist. Then if you want to use it as an ArrayList you can use `Arrays.asList(yourArray)`

Comment: If you already have a set size (9), an array would be efficient

Comment: I would use an array but it does not have a 'contains' method. It's just unfortunate that it doesn't have a more robust API.

Comment: `if (Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(something)){}`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in ths case you are entering en alement at position 5 but you have nothing there and there are no elements before - look here:

```
    ArrayList<Integer>  g = new ArrayList<Integer>(9);
    g.add(0, 10);
    g.add(1, 20);
    g.add(2, 30);
    g.add(3, 40);

    for(Integer v: g) System.out.print(v + " ");
    System.out.println();

    g.add(2,99);

    for(Integer v: g) System.out.print(v + " ");
    System.out.println();

    g.add(88); // use this to just push value at the end

    for(Integer v: g) System.out.print(v + " ");
    System.out.println();
```

yields:

```
10 20 30 40 
10 20 99 30 40 
10 20 99 30 40 88
```